# Report To Show Objects Not Used

Tags: admin

Is there a quick method or tool which would provide me with a rundown of the number of records existing for each object ? I'm doing a cleanup of my system and would like to see what objects do not have many records and can be deleted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Salesforce Classic:

Navigate to the setup menu.

From there, click on `System Overview`, and then click the "XX.X GB" number under `Data Storage`.

That takes you to a page that details the `SObjects` and `Custom Settings` that are taking up your data storage space. This data includes the number of records for each object.

The direct url is `https://<your Pod>.salesforce.com/setup/org/orgstorageusage.jsp?id=<Your Org Id>`

Comment: This is really nice